# Generate range hours and range numbres SQL/HQL

Tags: sql, time, hive, hiveql

I have a problem with a table.I currently have this empty hours table and I need to fill it automatically with a query in Hiveql. The idea is to generate:

- In the first column "key"  values between 000000 and 235959
- In the second column "hours" values between 00:00:00 and 23:59:59.

Now my table is empty:

```
KEY              |    HOURS     |
```

Future table that I need will be:

```
KEY     |    HOURS     |

1        00:00:00 

2         00:00:01 

...            ...

235959        23:59:59
```

How can I do this?

Comment: It is not clear how the key should be calculated. If the key for 00:00:00 is 1 and for 00:00:01 is 2, what the key for  00:01:01  -??  For 23:59:59 it looks like HH, mm, ss concatenated, but it is different in the beginning. for 00:00:00 it should be 0 or 000000 and for  00:00:01 it should be 1 or 000001... Or it can be simply seconds. 0,1,2...86399. Please clarify key calculation

Comment: Do you want key to be sequence number starting with 1 (1-86400) OR HH, mm, ss concatenated (the same as value but without : delimiter), OR seconds (0-86399)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set hivevar:end=23*60*60+59*60+59;--sequence end in seconds

with seq as(
select posexplode(split(space((${end})),' ')) as (i,x)
)

select concat(HH,mm,ss) as key, concat_ws(':',HH,mm,ss) as hours
from
(
select i, --seconds, you can use it also as a key
       lpad(floor(i/3600),2,'0') HH, lpad(floor(i%3600/60),2,'0') mm, lpad(floor(i%3600%60),2,'0') ss
  from seq
)s;
```

Result:

```
... 
first rows skipped
...
235954  23:59:54
235955  23:59:55
235956  23:59:56
235957  23:59:57
235958  23:59:58
235959  23:59:59
Time taken: 6.737 seconds, Fetched: 86400 row(s)
```

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your help! It is exactly this, but how could I insert it into the table once generated in a hive?

thank you

Comment: @Pilar Add this `insert overwrite table your_table` before this line: `select concat(HH,mm,ss) as key, concat_ws(':',HH,mm,ss) as hours`

Comment: This works great !! Thank you very much you have solved my day!